# how to skip the inverted commas when selecting a column from MySQL

Tags: mysql

There is a table with fields `name`, `age`, `city` and `state`. Now I need to select rows based on city name. The value of the column `city` is surrounded with `"`, for example `"LA"`.

How can I write a SELECT statement for getting data based on city.

Comment: so in few hours you will change your question again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just suggestion, if you are collecting and storing the information in the table to be queried later (ie you are in control of the input), try to clean the data up before storing it to make it easier to query?

If the input has quotes and white space, clean that before inserting the values into the table.   Use programming to do this, or mySQL: TRIM() and REPLACE() to remove the characters that might make a query hard to build and then store the resulting value into the table.

Of course, if you do not have control of the input data, that is where the answers above and the challenge to a programmer begins, trying to figure out the different input possibilities and dealing with that.

Answer (score 4):

`\"` is the escape combination for double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city = '\"LA\"';
```

See [MySQL documentation "String Literals"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE city  LIKE '%LA%'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE city  REGEXP '^[[:space:]]*LA[[:space:]]*$'
```

Comment: `%LA%` will find anything where the letters `LA` are present, so for example Dallas, Philadelphia or Las Vegas. The regular expression won't even match `"LA"`, as `"` is not a [white-space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) at all.

Comment: You just didn't see the original post :-)